# Javascript includes method does not work with MongoDB IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I was trying to use includes method to check existing MongoDB Id in an array but it is always returning false.

Is it a some kind of bug in the includes method or am I doing something wrong below is my code

```
  let user = req.user._id;
  let keyword= req.query.q;
  let userSearchHistory = await UserSearchHistory.findOne({searchKeywords: keyword}).exec();

  if (!userSearchHistory.users.includes(user))
  {

  }
```

where users in my database is an array with ObjectId refering to user collection

I also tried converting user object

```
   let user= mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id);
```

But still the same result. 
Converting ObjectIds to String working for me but then I have to remove the references in my model what is the proper way to handle this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably happening because userSearchHistory.users returns an array of objectIds.
You can try replacing `userSearchHistory.users.includes(user)` with `userSearchHistory.users.map(user=>user.toString()).includes(user)`.

This  way you will be able to  convert the array of objectIds to array of strings before applying 'includes' function.

Edit : Did you try trimming spaces in 'req.user._id' by using req.user._id.trim() and then casting it to objectId?